# What is the difference between a human and a mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant

What is the difference between humans and mutants in *X-Men*? Are mutants born to normal humans? Also, how do mutants get their powers? Are they born with them?

Comment: can any one delete this question?

Comment: @RANSARA009 You can delete the question, if you first unaccept the answer from KyloRen (click the green tick again). However, there's no need for you to do so unless you really want to - since you've now specified that you're asking about *Mutant Chronicles* rather than *X-Men*, I think this is a better question. You may also like to chat about it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39438/room-for-ancientswordrage-and-ransara009), where it looks like another mod has invited you.

Comment: @RANSARA009 - You don't need to delete it. How about this? Change this question back to X-Men. I'll put the X-Men tag back. Then you can ask a separate question about [tag:mutant-chronicles].

Comment: @RANSARA009 - Try asking a similar question (the one you originally intended) about [tag:mutant-chronicles] now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote from Marvel Universe,

> Human mutants are considered to be of the subspecies Homo sapiens superior or simply Homo superior, an evolutionary progeny of Homo sapiens, and are considered the next stage in human evolution, though whether this is true or not is a subject of much debate in-universe.
>   Unlike Marvel's mutates, which are characters who develop their powers only after exposure to outside stimuli or energies (such as the Hulk, Spider-Man, The Fantastic Four, and Absorbing Man), mutants are those whose mutations are pre-natal, and whose powers typically manifest at puberty.

So going off that, mutants are a subspecies Homo sapiens superior that manisfest during puberty. Rather than those who have become a mutants via outside stimuli or energies.

Comment: I don't think it's about X-men

Comment: In our universe, mutants are legally classified as not human... granted, the legal precedent has to do with weather their actions figures count as 'dolls' (intended to be depicted as human) or 'other toys' (nonhuman creatures) for the purposes of import tariff - but it is still amusing and perhaps relevant to the question.   I found the information in this article (https://nickkam.com/2010/05/05/mutants-are-people-too/)